# IF Statement Budget File setup for Monthly Amounts

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a budget formula and am stuck on the termination date, I can't get the formula to work if a tenant will remain all year (no termination date). It works perfectly if a tenant has a termination date. These formulas are for the monthly budget numbers, ie Jan-June columns. Many thanks for any response.

```
 A        B           C               D               E           F   G  H    I   J    K
SqFt  BaseRentPSF 2014BaseRentInc Dateofincrease TerminationDate Jan Feb Mar Apr May June
10000   15.00        15.25       05/01/2013
```

My current formula is:`ROUND(IF(F$1>$E2,"0",IF($D2="",($A2*$B2)/12,IF(F$1<$D2,($A2*$B2)/12,($A2*$C2)/12))),0)`

Comment: Is your first row (1) column headings? If so, how is the first `IF` comparing `F$1` to `$E2`? Should you be looking at `F2`? The third `IF` is the same way.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to replace the $E2 in the condition `F$1>$E2` with an IF statement checks whether $E2 is empty. If $E2 is empty, the statement substitutes an appropriate value so that the formula produces the result you desire; if $E2 is not empty, it simply uses the value in the cell.
For example, ROUND(IF(F$1>**IF($E2="",12/31/2013,$E2)**,"0",IF($D2...

I'm not quite sure what the appropriate value should be, since, at first glance, the `F$1>$E2` in your formula appears to be comparing a date value with a string such as "Jan", "Feb", etc. (This is the issue raised by CharlieRB). My example shows 12/31/2013 solely as a placeholder for illustrating the form the IF statement should take.